# Eclipse dsl application cannot hide unused perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, dsl

I'm working on eclipse application that provide IDE for internal DSL. DSL infrastructure is generated by xtext(2.7.3) platform. I would like to hide a few perspectives that is not useful for end-user of my application(Java, Debug, PDE etc.) I found one approach via activities. I've created the following fragment of plugin.xml

```
<extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
        <activity id="hauweg" name="hauweg-den-xxxx">
            <!-- this makes sure the matching stuff will never be enabled -->
            <enabledWhen>
                <with variable="true">
                    <equals value="false"/>
                </with>
            </enabledWhen>
        </activity>
        <!-- match all perspectives except org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective -->
        <activityPatternBinding activityId="hauweg" pattern=".*DebugPerspective"/>
        <activityPatternBinding activityId="hauweg" pattern=".*JavaPerspective"/>
        <activityPatternBinding activityId="hauweg" pattern=".*JavaHierarchyPerspective"/>
        <activityPatternBinding activityId="hauweg" pattern=".*JavaBrowsingPerspective"/>
        <activityPatternBinding activityId="hauweg" pattern=".*PDEPerspective"/>
        <activityPatternBinding activityId="hauweg" pattern=".*TeamSynchronizingPerspective"/>
    </extension>
```

1. xxx.xxx.xxx.ui plugin the most part of this plugin is generated by xtext platform
2. xxx.xxx.xxx.product plugin that contains product eclipse configuration

I've tried to put mentioned fragment to both plugin.xml but it does not help me. 
Also I would like to find out the following items:

1. can I do it programmatically only?
2. can I do it by declarative way only?
3. Should I use both mentioned ways?
4. Which plugin shall contains this declaration?

I use Eclipse 4 (Luna).

Answer (score 0):

Your `enabledWhen` is invalid, remove this. Unless you specify a `defaultEnablement` entry for an activity it defaults to being disabled.

Programmatically you can use:

```java
IWorkbenchActivitySupport workbenchActivitySupport = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActivitySupport();

IActivityManager activityManager = workbenchActivitySupport.getActivityManager();
```

to get the activity support and activity manager interfaces which give you some control over activities - but you still need to define them in the plugin.xml

If you are making an Eclipse RCP you may be able to just not include the JDT and other plugins in your RCP build. In that case you will not need to suppress the perspectives.